# Injecting hibernate Session (not EntityManager) into DAO (with JEE6)

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to inject hibernate Session into DAO.
The DAO is injected into a EJB 3.1 Stateless Bean with CDI.

**I don't want to use EntityManager. I prefer Hibernate Session directly.**
But using with EJB, the application server (JBoss 7) try to inject EntityManager, not hibernate Session.

And I'm getting the follow error when the DAO is creating:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.hibernate.Session field com.mycompany.persistence.dao.RoleDAO.session to org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager`

My codes:

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="MyPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MyDS</jta-data-source>

        <class>com.mycompany.entity.MyEntity</class>
        <class>com.mycompany.entity.OtherEntity</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**RoleBean.java** (the EJB)

```
@Stateless
@Remote(RoleRemote.class)
public class RoleBean implements RoleRemote {
    @Inject
    private RoleDAO roleDAO;

}
```

**RoleDAO.java**

```
@Named
public class RoleDAO {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "MyPU")
    private Session session;
}
```

And the error:
    `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.hibernate.Session field com.mycompany.persistence.dao.RoleDAO.session to org.jboss.as.jpa.container.TransactionScopedEntityManager`

Is it possible to inject hibernate Session (not EntityManager) in EJB environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not that way. I'm not even sure how you would go about doing it without having to write a bunch of boilerplate to join the transaction and whatnot. My advice is to use `EntityManager.getDelegate()` and cast it to the Hibernate Session.